# Parametrized module types

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to build a hierarchy of module types which depend on each other. In Coq I can write something like this:

```
Module Type Foo.
  Parameter t:Type.
End Foo.

Module Type Bar1 (T:Foo).
  Parameter f1: T.t -> T.t.
End Bar1.

Module Type Bar2 (T:Foo).
  Parameter f2: T.t -> T.t.
End Bar2.

Module Ex (F:Foo) (B1: Bar1 F) (B2:Bar2 F).

End Ex.
```

How would I express it in OCaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on gsg's answer, if you have a more complex `Foo` module type, you can use `with module` instead of `with type`, and have a module specification in both `Bar` types, as in the following example:

```
module type Foo =
sig
  type t
end

module type Bar1 = sig
  module F: Foo
  val f1: F.t -> F.t
end

module type Bar2 = sig
  module F: Foo
  val f2: F.t -> F.t
end

module Ex (F: Foo) (B1: Bar1 with module F = F) (B2: Bar2 with module F = F) =
struct

let f3 x = B2.f2 (B1.f1 x)

end

module Bar1_impl (F: Foo): Bar1 with module F = F = struct
  module F = F
  let f1 x = x
end

module Bar2_impl (F: Foo): Bar2 with module F = F = struct
  module F = F
  let f2 x = x
end

module F: Foo with type t = int = struct type t = int end

module M = Ex(F)(Bar1_impl(F))(Bar2_impl(F))

let x = M.f3 0;;
```

Comment: I like this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Ocaml does not directly support parameterised module types. However, you can emulate them by wrapping a parameterised module around them:

```
module type Foo =
sig
  type t
end

module Bar (X : Foo) =
struct
  module type T =
  sig
    val f : X.t -> X.t
  end
end

module Ex (F : Foo) (B : Bar(F).T) = ...
```

A bit more clumsy, but has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Module types do not take arguments. However, this particular pattern can be expressed by `with type`:

```
module type FOO = sig
  type t
end

module type BAR1 = sig
  type t
  val f1 : t -> t
end

module type BAR2 = sig
  type t
  val f2 : t -> t
end

module Ex (F:FOO) (B1 : BAR1 with type t = F.t) (B1 : BAR2 with type t = F.t) = struct
end
```

Comment: If I have multiple definitions inside FOO it might get little clumsy. I've also seen 'Include FOO" syntax. Not sure if it could help here...